# Merge the tags form and forms

Tags: discussion, tags

See [forms](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forms) (93 questions) and [form](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/form) (111 questions). One has to die! :)

Which one should be canonical?

### Update

Merged to [forms](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forms).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We typically go with plural for generic concepts ( [functions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functions), [buttons](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buttons), [constants](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constants) and so on).